# How to count subscribers of certain topic - Websocket, Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, data-structures, websocket

I'm currently working on the backend of a chat application. Of course, messages in chat work with Websockets as well to implement real-time communication.
Now I faced a problem: I need to indicate how many users joined the chat room.
When user enters chat room - he subscribing to the certain topic and sends message to that topic:

```
@MessageMapping("/chat.join/{id}")
    @SendTo("/topic/chat-channel/{id}")
    public ChatMessage joinChannel(@DestinationVariable("id")String destId,
                                   @Payload ChatMessage body,
                                   SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
        User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        ChatMessage modifiedMessage = chatService.joinChannel(body, user.getId(), destId);

        //we put channelId and userId to sessionAttributes for manipulate with that using HandlerInterceptor
        headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("userId", modifiedMessage.getSender());
        headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("channelId", modifiedMessage.getReceiver());
        return body;
```

Now every time when a user subscribes to a certain topic - I want to increment the counter which will display the number of chat room members. I decided to implement it with `Cache`, but every guide that I've found said:

> Caching should be used when data DON'T HAVE TO CHANGES FREQUENTLY

Can you please give me advice on which way to store members count should I use? Is it ok to write this value to the database (mongoDB)? Or better just implement some kind of `Singletone`?
Thanks

Comment: how do you know which users you have to notify of changes in a certain topic they subscribed to?

Comment: The idea is to increment the counter after the user subscribed, so after that counter could be updated in real-time for everyone who logged in. It can be done by subscribing on another topic (i.e. '/topic/memberCount') so every user that logged in can see that updates